# appendFileSync not producing full file when uploading chunks to express with React

Tags: reactjs, express

I am trying to implement chunk upload in express:

```
const cors = require('cors');
const express = require('express');
const md5 = require('md5');
const fs = require('fs');

const app = express()
const port = 4000

app.use(cors({origin: 'http://localhost:3000'}));
app.use(express.raw({type: 'application/octet-stream', limit: '100mb'}));

app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
    const { name, currentChunkIndex, totalChunks } = req.query;
    const isFirstChunk = parseInt(currentChunkIndex) == 0;
    const isLastChunk
        = parseInt(currentChunkIndex) === parseInt(totalChunks) - 1;
    
    const ext = name.split('.').pop();
    const data = req.body.toString().split(',')[1];

    const buffer = Buffer.from(data);
    const tempFilename = 'tmp_' + md5(name + req.ip) + '.' + ext;

    if (isFirstChunk && fs.existsSync('./uploads/' + tempFilename)) {
        fs.unlinkSync('./uploads/' + tempFilename)
    }

    fs.appendFileSync('./uploads/' + tempFilename, buffer)

    if (isLastChunk) {
        const finalFileName = Date.now() + '.' + ext;
        fs.renameSync('./uploads/' + tempFilename, './uploads/' + finalFileName);
    }

    res.send('ok');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

My call in react uses the following worker:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const chunkSize = 1 * 1000000; //(10 MB)

const fileReader = blob => {
    return new Promise((resolve, _) => {
        const onloadHandler = e => {
            const data = e.target.result;
            resolve(data)
        };
    
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = e => onloadHandler(e);
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    });
};


const uploadWorker = file => {
    return new Promise(async(resolve, reject) => {
        const totalChunks = Math.ceil(file.size / chunkSize);
        console.log(`total chunks ${totalChunks}`);
        let currentChunkIndex = 0;
    
        while (currentChunkIndex < totalChunks) {
            console.log(`current chunk ${currentChunkIndex}`);
            const from = currentChunkIndex * chunkSize;
            const to = Math.min(from + chunkSize, file.size);
            const blob = file.slice(from, to);
            const data = await fileReader(blob);
    
            const params = new URLSearchParams();
            params.set('name', file.name);
            params.set('size', file.size);
            params.set('currentChunkIndex', currentChunkIndex);
            params.set('totalChunks', totalChunks);
    
            const headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'};
            const url = 'http://localhost:4000/upload?' + params.toString();

            await axios.post(url, data, { headers });
            currentChunkIndex += 1;
        }
        resolve();
    });
};

export default uploadWorker;
```

When I debug on express I can see that it's receiving each chunk correctly and it is indeed saving data to `uploads` however the final file it just a binary file, if I try to send a video I am unable to watch the video.

Also the saved file is 8.4mb compared to 6.3mb of the original...

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you realize that a server should not be using any `fs.xxxxxSync()` methods in any request handlers as that ruins your server's scalability.  It blocks the single thread and prevents any processing of multiple requests at once.

Comment: I didn't realise that thanks. I'm a newbie to chunked uploads. Plan to switch to streams after I get this working.

Comment: IMO, it's kind of silly to write and debug it one way and then switch to streams and write it all over again.  Just learn how to do it with streams.

Comment: Also, uploading separate pieces like this and implementing your own from-scratch client and server chunking and reassembly is very unusual.  The browser already knows how to upload large files if you will just let it do it and then you can use an upload library like multer on the server-side to capture the upload.  That's how uploads are usually done.

Comment: Multer is for express. Do I still need to send the data in chunks from the client?

Comment: Yes, multer is for the server-side of uploads.  No, you don't have to send the file in chunks.  You use the built-in capabilities of the browser to upload the whole file for you as a flow-controlled stream.

Comment: You don't show the whole client-side of what you're trying to do, but usually file uploads are done via a form post that contains one or more `<input type="file">` tags.  If you let the browser post the form, it will handle the files and their encoding for you and multer will decode them on the Express side of things.

Comment: Thanks! I'll research this more. However I read multer isn't good for large files because it doesn't support streams, is this true?

Comment: You'd have to describe what you're trying to do on the server with streams.  Multer will stream an incoming upload to a file and has other options for handling the incoming data.  Once multer has captured the data, it's up to you what you do with the data.